# creating a Dice class that returns a random value

Tags: java

We were given this task which I am having a hard time trying to finish because I am usually more comfortable with my way of programming but the code given is unfinished.

The task is to create a Dice class using only the Dice() as the constructor and and the roll() as a method. We must use the imported Random class. Random has a method called `nextInt(int)` which takes an integer as a parameter and returns a random integer between 0(inclusive) and the given parameter(exclusive). For example:

```
r.nextInt(100);
```

returns a number from 0-99

The given code was:

```
package rpg;
import java.util.Random;   

public class Dice {    
    private Random r;

    /** 
     * Instantiate the object r 
     */    
    public Dice(){ 
     // Returns a random integer between 1 and 6
    }

    public int roll(){

    }    

}
```

Comment: so, you are given step by step what to implement. what is stopping you?

Comment: Upon instantiation (i.e., in the constructor) you'd want to initialize the RNG and assign to the `r` field. Then, inside the `roll` method you should invoke said RNG. Both are single -statements- lines.

Comment: `r.nextInt(6) + 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this using `ThreadLocalRandom`:

```
int randomValue;
public Dice(){
    randomValue = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 6);
}
```

And then return this value on using `roll()`.

```
public int roll(){
    return randomValue;
}
```

As according to your requirement but it's not good to approach as if you want to use it you have to initialize dice again and again.

So it's better to put `Dice` method code to `roll` like this:

```
public int roll(){
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 6);
}
```